Как передать GET параметры в PHP? (Nginx)
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?do=user&po=$1$is_args$args;
}

Необходимо, передать свои + те что будут в URL.
К примеру так, как выше написано, в PHP:
$_GET

Содержит массив из 2: do и po.
Если пользователь допишет свои параметры, к примеру:
/index.php?do=user&po=2&g=5

В PHP по прежнему $_GET будет содержать 2 параметра.
Не понимаю, как сделать чтобы и свои были по умолчанию и пользовательские?
Чтобы с пользовательскими GET можно было работать...

Убрать $is_args$args, nginx и так добавляет все параметры

Не знаю в чем дело, у меня nginx не добавляет пользовательских get. Только те что пропишу в конфиге когда парсю url. В чем тут может быть дело?

&$args - так работает...
